# Invalid use of template name error when calling function in boost v1.58

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I have a small C++ project that leverages the boost library (version 1.58) and am getting an error when calling boost::asio::strand. My syntax appears to be wrong but I can't figure out how.

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TCPNETWORK_H_
#define TCPNETWORK_H_

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

using boost::uint32_t;
using boost::uint16_t;
using boost::uint8_t;

using boost::int32_t;
using boost::int16_t;
using boost::int8_t;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Hive;
class Acceptor;
//class Connection;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this< Connection >
{
        friend class Acceptor;
        friend class Hive;

private:
        boost::shared_ptr< Hive > m_hive;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
        boost::asio::strand m_io_strand;


        boost::posix_time::ptime m_last_time;
        std::vector< uint8_t > m_recv_buffer;
        std::list< int32_t > m_pending_recvs;
        std::list< std::vector< uint8_t > > m_pending_sends;
        int32_t m_receive_buffer_size;


        boost::asio::deadline_timer m_retryTimer ;
        int32_t m_retryTimerInterval;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer m_connectTimer;
        int32_t m_connectTimerInterval;

        boost::asio::deadline_timer m_sendTimer;
        int32_t m_sendTimerInterval;

        void DispatchSendTimer( const boost::system::error_code & error );
        void HandleSendTimer( const boost::system::error_code & error );


        volatile uint32_t m_error_state;
```

The error message I am getting concerns the following line in this code:

```
boost::asio::strand m_io_strand;
```

And the error message I am getting follows:

```
../include/TCPNetwork.h:53:9: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list
```

How should I reference m_io_strand then?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. I should add that I'm more of a LAMP person and C++ falls into my lap every so often. So, I'm trying to use and understand it but I need a bit of handholding, hence the question.

Comment: I mean we need something to copy paste and compile, without modification and without the stuff irrelevant to the question. This is to the benefit of your's, our's and future readers', as it makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: For example, [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jhm9IR2BmDSAeuYU) compiles perfectly fine, and clearly isn't the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thank you for this! I hadn't come across wandbox.org and is terribly helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write `boost::asio::io_service::strand` instead of `boost::asio::strand`. Also you should initialize your `strand` with `io_service` object in constructor of your class.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance--it's been 20-25 years since I worked with C++ with any regularity.

How do I initialize it as you described?

Comment: ```boost::asio::io_context::strand strand(io_context);```